# Use of $ operate in mongodb php query

Tags: php, mongodb

From MongoDB Documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/
one can use `$` operator to update inner field, like for given example

```
    { "_id" : 4, "grades" : [ { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
                              { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
                              { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 } ] }
```

Use the positional $ operator to update the value of the std field in the embedded document with the grade of 85:

```
    db.students.update( { _id: 4, "grades.grade": 85 }, { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 } } )
```

Can somebody please explain me how `$` is playing a role? Why MongoDB developers didn't make it simpler, like we can find document with `"grades.grade":85` and also update with `"grades.std":6`? Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The positional `$` operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document.
Without `$`, you would have to perform extra steps to get the index of the matched element. Otherwise the index would be hardcoded.

Update example:

```
db.students.update( { _id: 4, "grades.grade": 85 }, { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 })
```

`"grades.grade":85` is `` find a document where 'grades' has 'grade' set to `85 ``.

`"grades.2.std":6` reads as `within 'grades', set 'std' to 6 for the element at index 2`.

`"grades.$.std:6"` reads as `within 'grades', set 'std' to 6 for the first matched element`.

`"grades.std":6` sounds like `within 'grades', for all elements set 'std' to '6'`. In MongoDB 2.6, this isn't a [supported feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243).